Provider and identifier columns of firebase authentication table is empty after user is logged in with `signInWithCustomToken`
In my nextjs project, by using next-auth v5 (with firebase adapter) I'm trying to log user in by calling signInWithCustomToken alongside providing some claims that shows user has been authenticated with google. But when I do, in my users section in authentication page of firebase console, the provider is not reflected:

The custom token has been created using admin.auth().createCustomToken() and then attached to my session object like so in my auth.ts file as explained here in callbacks section of the docs:
session: async ({ session, token }) => {
  if (session.user) {
    if (token.sub) {
      session.user.id = token.sub;

      const firebaseToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(token.sub, {
        provider: 'google', // For testing purposes I hard-coded this but in reality it's coming from somewhere else
      });
      session.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
    }
  }
  return session;
}

I logged the firebaseToken above and decoded it with jwt.io and it correctly contain my claims.
Here's the Provider component that I call signInWithCustomToken in.
async function syncFirebaseAuth(session: Session) {
  if (session && session.firebaseToken) {
    try {
      await signInWithCustomToken(auth, session.firebaseToken);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error siging in with custom token', err);
    }
  } else {
    auth.signOut();
  }
}

export default function FirebaseAuthProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session) return;

    syncFirebaseAuth(session);
  }, [session]);

  return <>{children}</>;
}

Any ideas on how I should be passing claims so that I would have the correct provider (and identifier) icon in my user's list in firebase console like shown in screenshot above?

Are you expecting the result of createCustomToken to change the way the user appears in the Firebase console?  I'm not sure that makes sense.  The identifier and provider information there is what was known about user at time the user account was created, not at the time the user was signed in.  Also, those fields have nothing to do with any custom claims you attached to the account. A user can be "signed in" any number of times on any number of devices, and the console isn't going to know anything about that, because all of that state is stored in the client.

I don't know the internals of the system to be honest. NextAuth provides the following functions when we provide a config to it, like so:
const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({ /* config */ })
And I use:
signIn('google')
to sign user in (create an account for them). It should insert a row in that table right?

I would only expect the provider information to be updated when using the Firebase-specific APIs (not nextjs specific API) for registering users.  For example, look at the documentation for Google sign-in, among many others you can see in the outline on the left. Accounts created this way happen on the client using Firebase backends, not your own backend.  If you're expecting your custom account creation and sign-in to populate those fields in the console, I don't think it has ever worked or will ever work that way.  You are certainly free to contact Firebase support to file a feature request, but I don't think they will act on it.
If you want to see your custom data for your custom sign-in procedure, you'll likely have to build your own console or admin screen that shows what you want.
